# How to make a form always stay on top of another form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How to make a form always stay on top of another form.

Also both form's enabled property must be true

I don't wanna make use of topmost property.

Edit 1 :

Another similar question in C# says you can use [Form.Owner Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner.aspx) to do the trick , how to make use of this property ?

Edit 2 : The Owner Property works fine untill I try to open it the second time.

This is the error message I get

[image]

Comment: Why don't you want to use the TopMost property? That's the way it should be done.

Comment: Can't you use **ShowDialog()** ?

Comment: It sounds like Noob needs both forms to be enabled for input though V4Vendetta - that would only allow the top form to accept input.

Comment: @Russell Troywest- Yes you are right, I want both forms for input and I don't want my app to go top of other apps so I don't wanna use topmost property. Sorry My internet connection went out so i couldn't give a quick response

Comment: Then it sounds like you've answered your own question actually. The Owner property is probably what you want. Set the Owner property on the 'topmost' form to the form that should be in the background. See Vendettas response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need the **frm.ShowDialog()** instead of **frm.Show()**

frm is the other form you need to show over your current form and instead of using Show, this will make it as a dialog form over your current form (however you won't be able to select the parent form or the form behind it unless you close the **frm** form

**EDIT**

To enable edit on both forms

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.Owner = this;
frm.Show();
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: I need the parent, without the parent my app won't work the way I want it it to be

Comment: can I make it move along with the parent ?

Comment: I am not sure .. it would be lot of work in the **Move** event of the Form

Comment: Are you not creating a new instance ?

Comment: I did `Public frm as new Form2` (vb.net)