# How to make a form stay above another

Tags: c#, .net, windows, multithreading, winforms

In my .NET application I am showing a form with a "Please wait" message if some task takes a while to tell the user that the program still works. This form has to run in it's own thread since the main thread is the one doing work and therefore busy. [I read that one can use `Form.Owner` for this task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5854688/680151), but I don't think that works if the forms run on different threads.

The problem is that the wait form can be hidden behind the main form in which case the user couldn't see it and can't bring it to the front, since it has no task bar button (an it musn't have one).

My question is if it is possible to let the wait form stay above the main form without making it an AlwaysOnTop form (which would stay above ALL windows)?

Comment: Sure, you get an IllegalOperationException when you do this.  There are ways to patch around this, but then you get to figure out [why your program deadlocked](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsui_team/archive/2012/10/31/debugging-windows-forms-application-hangs-during-systemevents.userpreferencechanged.aspx), can be *hours* after you showed that window.  That was meant to scare you.  Use a worker thread to perform work, use the UI thread to display UI and you won't have a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Form.TopMost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property for this.

You can also use the following code:

```
protected void SetZOrder(IntPtr bottom, IntPtr top) {
    const int flags = 0x0002 | 0x0001; 
    NativeMethods.SetWindowPos(bottom, top, 0, 0, 0, 0, flags);
}
```

bottom - the pointer of the main form, top - the pointer of the wait form. To get a pointer, use Form.Handle property. And call the SetZOrder via the BeginInvoke method of the parent form.

Comment: TopMost makes the form stay on top of ALL windows, but I want it to just stay above my window.

Comment: It doesn't quite work when the thread of the bottom window is busy, but I think it is the best I can achieve. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your main thread should not be doing work. It should be handling UI and nothing else.

The right way to do this is to perform any and all time-consuming work in an asynchronous manner (e.g. in a separate thread), and keeping all of your user interface in the main thread. Then you can simply show the "Please wait" message form by calling the `Form.ShowDialog()` method. This will force focus to that dialog and keep it on top of its parent form (don't forget to pass the parent form reference to the `ShowDialog()` method).

Without a code example, I can't say exactly how this would look in your specific scenario. But the general idea looks something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Form form = MyWaitMessageForm())
    {
        form.Shown += async (sender1, e1) =>
        {
            await Task.Run(() => MyLongRunningWork());
            form.Close();
        }

        form.ShowDialog(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: .ShowDialog(parent) if you want no possible interaction with the parent form, and .Show(parent) if you want to be able to do anything on the parent (like copying text from a textbox).

Comment: Since the OP specifically asked to have `the wait form stay above the main form`, the correct method to call is `ShowDialog()` and not `Show()`.

Comment: It stays above on Show(parent) as well, but the parent is focusable. But will not come up above the child window. Just 2 ways  of doing the same but allowing for different usage. It is actually whats closest to AlwaysOnTop but only for that parent form (Requires ShowInTaskbar=false of course).

Comment: I see what you mean. I assumed that the OP wanted focus to stay on the dialog form (i.e. so that the user cannot interact with the parent form), but he doesn't actually say that, so maybe he doesn't want a modal form. In that case, you are correct: calling `Show(parent)` would be the appropriate method.

Comment: I know that this would be the ideal solution in most cases, but it is not possible in my case. There are things you cannot do in another thread. In my case that would be loading the ui and dealing with 3rd party components that are not thread safe and therefore need to run in the ui thread. But I agree this would be the best solution if it were possible.

Comment: Why not run the third-party components in _their_ own STA thread? They're the trouble-makers, make them play in their own sandbox. :)

Comment: Because they have to interact with my ui directly

Comment: You do not need to run all the code on the UI thread. Run the long running task on a task/background thread and use this.Invoke(..) to do stuff that only works on the UI thread. It depends on how heavy you use the UI components. But some of the work could easily be offloaded to a task/background thread.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w61zzfwe(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Form1 testDialog = new Form1();
testDialog.ShowDialog(this)
```

Comment: A WinForms dialog needs to be disposed after it's closed.