# Updating the UI while a long running operation runs async, cant use Application.DoEvents

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am working on a winforms application which calls a method in a class library to get data. I dont want the UI thread to be blocked if this process takes time.
while the data is being fetched from the database, which happens in async using backgroundWorker, I send an event to the UI which calls `Application.DoEvents();` and the UI remains responsive.

The problem is because of `Application.DoEvents()` the user can click on another button on the UI and send more requests. We cant let that happen. Also I cant open a modal dialog box on the UI while the data fetching work isnt over, the dialog box opens after the data has been fetched!!

simply put : Is there a way to give the user an experiense of responsive UI without Application.DoEvents 
Or
Can I disable the events the application is generation for sometime ?

Comment: First: forget about calling `Application.DoEvents()`. It is never needed, and if your code uses it, it's broken right out of the starting gate. Remove your use of `Application.DoEvents()` and then work to a solution from there. Second: you must be using `BackgroundWorker` wrong, because `Application.DoEvents()` wouldn't even help in a scenario where `BackgroundWorker` were being used correctly. You should show your code, so that we can understand what's wrong with it. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Also, see my answer to another related question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27094868/3538012 That answer shows how you can display a model dialog during an asynchronous operation (to prevent interaction with the UI), by showing the dialog first, and then using the `Shown` event as the place where you start the asynchronous operation.

Comment: The request from UI layer goes to the business layer and from there to the database layer. Its an existing application and we cant modify the UI layer to implement the background worker. even though that would have been simple and would have worked for sure but it would require code change in a lot of places. The idea is to let the DB call work async and a while loop waits for the call to be over and send events to the UI layer. The UI does App...DoEvents and UI is responsive.

Comment: But it's your loop that is causing the problem. Again, no code posted means there's no way to explain precisely how to fix your code. "we cant modify the UI layer" doesn't make sense; you obviously have modified it if you have added a loop with calls to `DoEvents()`. I _guarantee_ you that you don't need `DoEvents()`, but without a real description of your scenario, one that includes an actual code example, I can't offer any more guidance than that.

Comment: Peter I am using .Net 3.5 and cant use Tasks. However I used the begininvoke on the ui (during the event raise by DB layer) to display a dialog box and the box appears after the response has arrived. Although a lable on the form would update immediately.

Comment: `Task` is not the only way to execute something in a background thread. See e.g. `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()` or even `BackgroundWorker`. Your DB layer should not involve itself with UI at all, nor should it need to.

Comment: Looks like your application is a complete mess, totally lacking proper separation of concerns, where DB related code is messing with UI stuff, typical for winforms proyects. Reminds me of [Synchronization By Modal](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/Synchronization-by-Modal). I suggest you start reading on async patterns **before** you touch a single line of code. And please, Remove `Application.DoEvents()` from everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

On .NET 3,5 the [Backgroundworker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95%29.aspx) is used to do work on a worker thread. It also supports notifications to the UI thread while doing this. On 4.0+ [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110%29.aspx) are used to do this. Both implementations doesnt require `Application.DoEvents`. This should also be avoided

Comment: I am using 3.5 and the UI is responsive. The issue is i dont want the user to raise events by clicking on controls. I can disable the controls but then there is an overhead to maintain the control state.

Comment: Doing work on a background thread *requires* you to update the user interface with the correct state.  Otherwise, why even bother going through the work of making the UI responsive?

Comment: @BTownTKD: when correctly implemented, simply running the task in a separate thread is all that's needed to ensure the UI remains responsive. The UI only fails to be responsive when some code in the UI thread blocks, which it doesn't need to do when the operation is run in a separate thread. No calls to `DoEvents()` needed.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: you and I are on the same page.  The OP was saying he doesn't want users to be able to click buttons, but he also doesn't want to do the work of enabling/disabling buttons to prevent it.

Comment: @BTownTKD: ah, okay. I see what you meant...I thought you were responding to the answer, suggesting that `DoEvents()` is needed. Note that disabling the UI is simple: display a modal dialog above it. This does not require explicitly disabling individual elements of the underlying UI. Note also that a UI can be "responsive" without accepting input or showing progress; simply being able to be redrawn as necessary (e.g. when window is minimized, overlapped, etc.) can be considered "responsive". (But I agree showing progress is better, when possible...at the least, an indeterminate progress bar)

Comment: @peter you are correct about the thread not making the UI unresponsive. I get that. but the problem is I cant have a thread spawned over the UI layer. It has to happen in the DB layer. So the UI waits. Also while the DB is busy I keep sending events to the UI which DoEvent and make the UI responsive. This causes issues. Either i can somehow cancel the events on UI or I can show a dialog box. but i dont know why the dialog box appears after the response is received eventhough I am using begininvoke.

Comment: "have a thread spawned over the UI layer" doesn't even make sense. I have no idea what that's supposed to mean. In any case, as I have mentioned before, if you don't post a good code example, no one can give you a good answer about your code.